# SQL overwrites data when two users input at the same time (Python)

Tags: python, mysql, sql, telegram

I'm creating a Telegram bot where users can create offers of items they want to sell. It works perfectly fine, when users create it one by one. But when they do it at the same time, the data is corrupted. They get NULL or overwritings in some fields.

I used SQLite and I read that SQLite might be the issue, so I switched to MySQL (mysql.connector) and still have this issue.

```
connMembers = mysql.connector.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", password = "qwerty", database = "testdb")
connItems = mysql.connector.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", password = "qwerty", database = "testdb")

def create_table_members():
    cursor = connMembers.cursor()
    sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Members" \
          "(FirstName TEXT, LastName TEXT, ChatID INTEGER UNIQUE)"
    cursor.execute(sql)
    connMembers.commit()
    cursor.close()

def create_table_items():
    cursor = connItems.cursor()
    sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " \
          "Items(FirstName TEXT, LastName TEXT, ChatID INTEGER, " \
          "ItemName TEXT, ItemPrice INTEGER, ItemID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY )"
    cursor.execute(sql)
    connMembers.commit()
    cursor.close()
```

Here's how I enter:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['CreateOffer'])
def handle_createoffer(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Enter Item Name")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, get_item_name)
```

After this step redirects me here:

```
def get_item_name(message):
    global CurrentID
    CurrentID = CurrentID + 1
    ItemName = message.text
    items_add(message.from_user.first_name, message.from_user.last_name, message.from_user.id, ItemName, 0, CurrentID)
    msg = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'What is your price?')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, get_item_price)
```

And then:

```
def get_item_price(message):
    try:
        ItemPrice = message.text
        if ItemPrice.isdigit():
            edit_item_price(ItemPrice, CurrentID)
        else:
            msg = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "not a digit")
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, get_item_price)
    except Exception as e:
        msg = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "ERROR" )
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, get_item_price)
```

To update a price I use this:

```
def edit_item_price(ItemPrice, ItemID):
    cursor = connItems.cursor()
    cursor.execute("UPDATE Items SET ItemPrice = %s WHERE ItemID = %s", (ItemPrice, ItemID))
    connItems.commit()
    cursor.close()
```

UPD: This is how I get CurrentID:

```
CurrentID = item_id_finder()

def item_id_finder():
    cursor = connItems.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT MAX(ItemID) FROM Items")
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    connItems.commit()
    cursor.close()
    if data[0][0] == None:
        return 0
    else:
        return data[0][0]
```

Example:

```
    User1 ItemName : ItemNameOne
    User2 ItemName : ItemNameTwo
    User2 ItemPrice : 40
    User1 ItemPrice : 20

    Expected output:
    User1 - ItemNameOne - 20
    User2 - ItemNameTwo - 40

    Real OutPut:
    User1 - ItemNameOne - 0
    User2 - ItemNameTwo - 20
```

Comment: You are doing update operation on table and that is supposed to change the existing data. Can you explain the issue with some sample data ?

Comment: The code you added in the update is fine, as long as you're running that before starting any of the concurrent handlers. There are ways it could be improved (there's no reason to `commit` a transaction that doesn't modify anything, you don't need to use `fetchall` just to ignore everything after the first row, you should almost never check anything `== None`, …), but none of that should make it not work.

Comment: Your detailed example happens to match exactly the flow of my "what could go wrong" example in my answer. I suspect you already get that—but if you need me to edit the answer to be more specific (using your actual numbers and names and so on), let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `global CurrentID`. That means there's a single value shared by all users.

Consider this flow:

- User 1 starts an offer, and the ID gets bumped to 23.
- While you're waiting for user 1's price, user 2 starts an offer, and the ID gets bumped to 24.
- While you're waiting for user 1's price and for user 2's price, one of them responds, and you update the price for item 24.
- Then the other one responds, and you update the price for item 24 again.

So, item 24 ends up with the price set by whichever user came last, and meanwhile, item 23 never gets updated at all, so its price is presumably still NULL (or whatever your default is).

---

So, first, you need to change `get_item_price` to take an ID as a parameter, instead of using the global:

```
def get_item_price(ItemID, message):
    # now use ItemID instead of CurrentID
```

And then you need to pass in the right value:

```
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, functools.partial(get_item_price, ItemID))
```

But how do you get that `ItemID` in a way that can't be interfered with by anyone else working at the same time?

I actually know nothing about Telegram. If it works by coroutines, you can be sure that you haven't been interrupted between that `CurrentID = CurrentID + 1` and the first potentially blocking call, which presumably is the message send, so you can just do this:

```
def get_item_name(message):
    global CurrentID
    CurrentID = CurrentID + 1
    ItemID = CurrentID
    # now use ItemID instead of CurrentID
```

If, on the other hand, it works by threads, where you can be interrupted at any time, you need some kind of synchronization mechanism, like a lock:

```
id_lock = threading.Lock()

def get_item_name(message):
    global CurrentID
    with id_lock:
        CurrentID = CurrentID + 1
        ItemID = CurrentID
    # now use ItemID instead of CurrentID
```

---

As suggested by the OP in a comment, there's an even better solution here if you can change the database schema—just make the ItemID auto-incrementing. In MySQL, that's:

```
ItemID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Then, change your `INSERT` statements to leave `ItemID` out of the specified columns, and get the [`lastrowid`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-lastrowid.html) property right after the `INSERT`:

```
ItemID = cursor.lastrowid
```

You still have to pass that `ItemID` along so it can be used by the `UPDATE` statement later (or, if you prefer, pass the cursor itself along), but you no longer need to worry about picking numbers in a concurrency-safe way with locks and an initialization function that has to go before any threads are started and so on.

Comment: I see, I wasted so much time thinking that SQLite was an issue, but apparently you're right. Thanks. I also updated a post a bit

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but just got an idea. While I'm still trying to figure things out, do you think this way can work:
What if I can auto increment ID when I create a table so I don't need to find ID and use it as global anymore?

Comment: @Jason Yes, making the ID an auto-incrementing field in the database is a great idea! Then you insert the row, and then `ItemID = cursor.lastrowid`. And then, even if you're using threads, as long as you're not sharing cursors between users, you don't need any other locking; the database library takes care of it for you.